# Display inline image with Ionic

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a small mobile app using Ionic and am struggling to display an image inline with a text.

```
            <ion-view title="Beer">
                <ion-content class="has-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col text-center">
                                <h2>Brooklyn</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-40">
                                <p style="text-align: right;"><b>Country:</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" >
                                <p style="text-align: left;"><img ng-src="img/flags-mini/us.png" /> United States</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>
```

As I'm very inexperienced with CSS I'm having a hard time to display the United States flag and have the < p > content vertically centralized. The way it's now the text is displayed at the bottom of the row and not in the center:

[image]

I have tried different things: tweaking the < div>'s to define inline css styles to try to bring the text up a bit, moving the flag to a separate col, defining margins, etc. Nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to get them aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way how you can do it:

```
<ion-view title="Beer">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                    <h2>Brooklyn</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-40">
                    <p style="text-align: right;"><b>Country:</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col" >
                    <img ng-src="img/flags-mini/us.png" style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;"/>
                    <p style="text-align: left;"> United States</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

So, what did I do? I took the `img` tag out of the `p` tag and added the `float:left; margin-right: 5px;` CSS rules to this image. Rest is left intact.

You can see the example working on Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwNqM

Comment: That's awesome - thank you, Nikola. 'United States' is now a bit above 'Country:' (ie in a slightly higher position). I'll play around to get them aligned - fun CSS exercise :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped! Sure, no probs, if you get stuck, just ping. Good luck!